# how to include a sub tex file in include file of latex

Tags: input, include

I already include file in `main.tex` like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

how to include a subfile in `chapter1.tex` like this(or recursive include):

```
\chapter{chapter1}

\include{subsection}
```

Comment: you can't nest \include. Use \input instead.

Comment: input still not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main.tex`, you can use `\include{}` or `\input{}`, see this [question about their difference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/).
Because you cannot use the `\include` in an nested way, you have to use `\input` in files that are already included (or inputed) themselves.

---

So you have to change the `\include` to an `\input` in your `chapeter1.tex`.